# Launch application on dialing number iOS

Tags: ios, swift, telephony

Is there any way to launch iOS application or its background activity on dialing a specific number ?

How to access the incoming call number ?

Is there any way to access call log information inside my application ?

Comment: Apple officially does not expose any public API to access the call log. You can hack all you want to access the call log but when submitting your app to Apple by sure it will be rejected. Just Refer this-https://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/

Comment: I think iOS would not allow to disturb native calling app, but recently I also needed to be able to record call, so as user hang out, previously opened app could catch it.

Comment: In short NO, you cannot!